# Trouble running socket.io in ports other than 80

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, port

I'm running express.js on port 80, so socket.io has to go on other port. The problem is that, then, I have to load socket.io on the client with:

```
<script src="http://my_domain:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Which is horrible because I have to change my_domain everytime I switch from local machine to host.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm running express.js on port 80, so socket.io has to go on other port.

Wrong.

You can run Socket.io and Express on the same port; just pass same same `http.Server` instance to both of them.